# Change JQuery .append output using nth-child if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, append

I'm listing 6 articles using .append(see below) and want to change which grid size they use depending on which iteration they are in the output. I have set this as var grid = 'x'. I want this to change depending on what child the article is of ul#news.

Using the code below, every article defaults to < li class="sm-12 m-3 cls" >

I believe the principles of what i'm doing to be correct, but something isn't working. Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.response.total; i++) {
    if ('ul#news li:nth-child(0)') {
        var grid = "sm-12";
    } else if ('ul#news li:nth-child(1)') {
        var grid = "sm-12 m-6";
    } else {
        var grid = "sm-12 m-3";
    };
    var thumbnail = data.response.results[i].blocks.main.bodyHtml;
    var title = data.response.results[i].webTitle;
    $('ul#news').append('<li class="' + grid + ' cls">' + thumbnail + '<h2>' + title + '</h2></li>');
};
```

Current Output

```
<ul id="events" >
  <li class="sm-12 m-3 cls"></li>
  <li class="sm-12 m-3 cls"></li>
  <li class="sm-12 m-3 cls"></li>
  <li class="sm-12 m-3 cls"></li>
  <li class="sm-12 m-3 cls"></li>
  <li class="sm-12 m-3 cls"></li>
</ul>
```

What I hope to achieve

```
<ul id="events" >
  <li class="sm-12 cls"></li>
  <li class="sm-12 m-6 cls"></li>
  <li class="sm-12 m-3 cls"></li>
  <li class="sm-12 m-3 cls"></li>
  <li class="sm-12 m-3 cls"></li>
  <li class="sm-12 m-3 cls"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the value in `'ul#news li:nth-child(0)'`?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I'm not sure what you mean, sorry?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan that's supposed to delineate the position in the ul#news

Comment: Those are only strings though and the strings are not checked against anything else. If the aim is to check if the element exist then should be more `$('ul#news li:nth-child(0)').size()` instead of just the selector string.

Comment: @GillesC - Thanks! I've updated the question - hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: What are to trying to check with `'ul#news li:nth-child(1)'`? Can you explain when the first two conditions should meet?

Comment: The question was clear, the conditions are not, try what I mentioned in the other comment, checking a string on its own doesn't do much but using the strings to check an element is found would give you what you want.

Comment: @TJ - I'm trying to check against it's position in the outputted list. I.e, the .append(ed) list is 6x list items. I want to change the class depending on an items position. So, the first item in a list should be <li class="sm-12 cls">, the second should be <li class="sm-12 m-6 cls"> and the remaining 4 should be <li class="sm-12 m-3 cls">. Sorry if I asked this in a backwards way! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors in the `if` condition is missing the jQuery constructor `$()`, also you seems to be assuming that the element is already in the `ul>`, but it's not there yet, So you need to count what is already in it. So your code should be something like:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.response.total; i++) {
  if ($('ul#news li').length == 0) { // currently empty, first element going to be inserted
    var grid = "sm-12";
  } else if ($('ul#news li').length == 1) { // second element going to be inserted
    var grid = "sm-12 m-6";
  } else {
    var grid = "sm-12 m-3";
  };
  var thumbnail = data.response.results[i].blocks.main.bodyHtml;
  var title = data.response.results[i].webTitle;
  $('ul#news').append('<li class="' + grid + ' cls">' + thumbnail + '<h2>' + title + '</h2></li>');
};
```

Comment: Thanks @TJ, that's exactly what I wanted! :)

Comment: @ElliottJames Also it looks like you can just use the loop variable to decide the class like `if (i == 0) { var grid = "sm-12"; } ` instead of querying DOM...

Comment: Brilliant! :) - Thanks again!